# How to response the user when he uncheck the checkboxlist control in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

AutoPostBack property is true when user select the Check box list it
this code I'm using

```
if (li.Selected)
{
    switch (num)
    {
       case 1 :
           lblname.Text = "CheckBox1 is selected";
           break;
    }
}
```

what code is written to response the user when he uncheck the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question in its entirety, but I think what you're looking for is what event to use to handle the user interaction.

If my understanding is correct, then you want to use the SelectedIntexChanged event on the CheckBoxList control.

You can see my code sample below.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkBoxList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="checkBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test2" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This markup above is the code on the aspx page.

```
protected void checkBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBoxList = sender as CheckBoxList;
    foreach (ListItem li in checkBoxList.Items)
    {
        switch (li.Selected)
        {
             case true:
                //Code to handle if the ListItem is selected goes here
                break;
             case false:
                //Code to handle if the ListItem is not selected goes here
                break;
             default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The C# code above is the code found on the aspx.cs (CodeBehind) file.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This approach is working But if there is four item in a Checkboxlist only the last item is responding true of false condition else item doesn't responding any condition

Comment: Are you using the switch implementation as provided above, or are you using the if statement as shown in your question?

Comment: Thank you I'm got My answer and I'm using Switch

Comment: Glad that it answered your question. :)